# The splitting in the decomposition theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

A special case, which I think is much older, of the Decomposition Theorem states that, for a projective smooth morphism $f: X \to Y$ of complex algebraic varieties, the higher direct image $Rf_* \mathbb{C}$ factors as a direct sum of its cohomology sheaf:

$$Rf_* \mathbb{C} = \oplus_i R^if_* \mathbb{C} [-i].$$ 
As far as I understand there are several proofs of this fact: one can either use Hodge theory to show this, or one can reduce mod a big enough prime $p$ and use the weights of Frobenious to show this.

In other words, if i'm not wrong here, there is a canonical family of isomorphisms 
$\phi_p$ between the left and the right hand sides of this equation, one for each prime $p$ such that the reduction map is an isomorphism. 
Are the $\phi_p$ different from one another? and if they do, how is the choice of splitting depends on $p$?

Comment: It's interesting that in "Theoreme de Lefschetz..." Deligne proves that the existence of a splitting follows from Hard Lefschetz, but does not give a canonical one, and says that there is an isomorphism "plus beau que les autres" (Remarque 1.8) but doesn't say what he means by this.

Comment: Of course this predates his theory weights, but maybe he was already thinking about using them.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger: Deligne discusses specific isomorphisms in his paper "Decompositions dans la categorie derivee".

Comment: @ulrich Thank you, I'll have a look. Does it answer the question?

Comment: @ulrich He defines a canonical splitting, but only after choosing the ample class $\eta$, and I'm not sure it's clear that the splitting is independent of the ample class.

Comment: It seems to me that the splitting that comes out of the reduction modulo a prime don't use projectivity more than as a tool to show purity of the projection, and in particular it should be independent of the embedding. Moreover, it is still unclear to me if the splittings coming from reductions and Frobenious depends on p or not. And there is a source in English? Thanks!

Comment: @PiotrAchinger: I don't think there is a splitting independent of choice of an ample class except in particular cases, e.g., abelian schemes.